# rxjs how to best convert args array to object

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am doing this with `withLatestFrom`:

```
.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(observable1$),
  map(([one, two]) => ({one, two})),
  tap((args) => { console.log(args) }}
)
```

and this with `forkJoin`:

```
.pipe(
  mergeMap((action) => forkJoin(
    of(action),
    observable1$.take(1),
    observable2$.take(1)
  )),
  map(([one, two, three]) => ({one, two, three})),
  tap((args) => { console.log(args) }} 
)
```

Both approaches convert the piped array to an object (which I find easier to manage).

But is there an easier way of converting the array to object format?
Could I map to an object inside mergeMap? Is there another operator to simplify the code? An answer to any one (or more) of these questions is welcome. thx

Comment: What you are doing is the recommended approach, as result selectors are now deprecated. Also, your `withLatestFrom` example doesn't look right, as as `one` will be the value emitted from the source observable - not from `observable1$`. I guess you could write your own operator if you could decide upon a naming convention for the object keys.

Comment: thanks cartant, you clearly know what you are talking about - add your comment as answer and I will accept - PS I fixed issue with `withLatestFrom`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several RxJS operators and functions currently support result selectors. For example, you could perform the mapping in the `forkJoin` call, like this:

```
.pipe(
  mergeMap((action) => forkJoin(
    of(action),
    observable1$.take(1),
    observable2$.take(1),
    (one, two, three) => ({ one, two, three })
  )),
  tap((args) => { console.log(args) }}
)
```

However, [result selectors are **now deprecated**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#result-selectors-removed-or-deprecated) - as removing them will significantly simplify both the implementations and the API - and the [recommended approach](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#result-selectors) is the one that you've taken: use the `map` operator.